# Can anybody remove a question that has several answers?

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions

My question got closed and I asked about deleting it via a flag. Only result was that my flag was considered `helpful`.

My question had several answers and one of them was accepted, there were also votes there. Why was it still not deleted? Is it due to the fact that it is not possible to anybody or was the flag reviewer only lazy?

> (nobody is asked for magic view abilities, only I ask for is it possible or not to do the delete)

Comment: A moderator can *definitely* delete the question, regardless of the number of answers/votes that it has. And *only* moderators can mark flags as valid/invalid, so one of them definitely processed your flag. Not sure why they decided not to honor your request and delete the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requests from the poster to delete their question are taken seriously. However, they are not always acted on.

When you post on Stack Exchange you are assigning some of your rights to the community with respect to the content - see the [licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) linked to at the foot of every page. Basically you don't have exclusive rights to the content any more and others rights have to be considered.

All dismissing a flag as "Valid" means is that

> the flags have merit but no further action is required

so the moderator who handled the flag could well have thought that while there was some merit in your flag, it wasn't necessary to delete the question.

If they had decided to delete the question then they could have.

Comment: Right, this. The thing that caught my eye, though, is that the question flagged for deletion was already closed. I'm not sure why a closed question would be adding enough value to the community to decline deletion.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that we signed an agreement with our blood^H^H^H^H^H^H action of posting here.